# Handling search view in Android (I know how to search a single word but here scenario is different)?

Tags: android, xml, search

I know how to search a single word but here what i want is if we search a single word whole paragraph should be displayed where that single word is present.

I am keeping some paragraphs in XML say about 10 paragraphs. If I search the word theft which is present in 3 paragraphs out of 10 then only 3 paragraphs should be displayed with highlighting the word theft present in that para.

please help me out with this and thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you have tried?

Comment: make a list of 10 paragraphs. then put that list into recyclerview. then when you search check if the single string word is contains in the paragraphs